# Cloning a repository from newly created gitlab account using Google Open ID

Tags: gitlab

I just started using gitlab and used google open ID. 
I cloned a repository and its asking me for a username and password.
How do I know what my password is ?

Answer (score 1):

To check your username, just visit GitLab.com and check the bottom-left corner. You should see your username there (cabargas in my example):

[image]

Then visit the [password section of your profile on GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com/profile/password/edit) and set-up your password there.